# Show $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2 dt$ converges when $f$ is integrable.

Tags: real-analysis

> A function $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is *integrable on* $\Bbb R$ if $f$ is Riemann integrable on all intervals and the improper integrable $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f|dt$$ exists and is finite.
> Show that if $f$ is bounded and *integrable on* $\Bbb R$, then $f^2$ is *integrable on* $\Bbb R$.

I have shown that $f^2$ is Riemann integrable on all intervals, but I have no idea how to show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2 dt$$ converges.

Can I write $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2 dt=\Bigl(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| dt\Bigr)\Bigl(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| dt\Bigr)$$?

Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are very simple examples to show that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2 dt=\Bigl(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| dt\Bigr)\Bigl(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f| dt\Bigr)$$ is not correct.

Answer for the old version of the question: This statement is false (unless you assume that $f$ is bounded on the whole real line). For example if $f(x)=n$ on $(n,n+\frac 1 {n^{3}})$ for $n=2,3,...$ and $0$ elsewhere then $f$ is integrable but $f^{2}$ is not.

Answer for the new version: Suppose $f$ is bounded, say $|f|\leq M$. Then $\int_x^{y} f^{2}(t) dt \leq M\int_x^{y}|f(t)| dt \to 0$ as $y>x \to \infty$. A similar result holds on the negative side. This implies that $\int_{0}^{y_n}f^{2}(x)dx $ is Cauchy sequence and hence it has a finite limit whenever  $y_n \to \infty$. Similarly for $\int_{x_n}^{0} f^{2}(t)dt$ when $x_n \to -\infty$. Hence $f^{2}$ is integrable.

Comment: I have added that $f$ is bounded, do you know how to show the improper integral exists? or I should what kind of test. thanks.

Comment: @StevenLu I have added a proof for that case.

Comment: Do you mean
$\int_{-x}^{y} f^{2}(t) dt \leq M\int_{-x}^{y}|f(t)| dt \to 0$ as $y>x$ and $x\to \infty$?

Comment: I am separating out integrability near $+\infty$ and integrability near $-\infty$. There was a typo. I have corrected it. @StevenLu

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the notation $\int_x^{y} f^{2}(x) dx \leq M\int_x^{y}|f(x)| dx \to 0$ as $y>x \to \infty$. We integrate $f$ with integrand $x$ and $y$ is some numbers $y>x$. Then if we let $x\to \infty$ does it means $y\to \infty$? and so the integral becomes something like $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}|f(x)| dx$ and it is $0$. Am I right?

Comment: I have read your argument after correction. I think you mean let $y>x$ and $x$ be fixed, then consider the integral $\int_x^{y} f^{2}(t) dt \leq M\int_x^{y}|f(t)| dt \to 0$. but I do not know why it will approach to $0$ as $y\to \infty$. By assumption $\int^\infty_{-\infty}|f|dt$ converges. It implies $\int^\infty_{c}|f|dt$ converges. Then $\int_x^{y} f^{2}(t) dt \leq M\int_x^{y}|f(t)| dt \leq M\int_x^\infty |f(t)|dt$. Then I want to ask why it approaches to $0$? thanks a lot.

Comment: @StevenLu If $\int_0^{T} |f(t)|dt \to L$ then $\int_x^{T} |f(t))|dt=\int_0^{T} |f(t))|dt-\int_0^{x} |f(t))|dt \to L-L=0$. This implies $\int_x^{\infty} |f(t))|dt \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I want to write the part you omit. First, since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f|dt$ converges, $\int_{-\infty}^0|f|dt$ converges. Hence, $\int_x^yf^2(t)dt\leq M\int_x^y|f(t)|dt\leq M\bigl(\int^0_x|f(t)|dt-\int^0_y|f(t)|dt\bigr)$ , where $x<y$, since it is true for all $y>x$, we let $x\to -\infty$, then we get $M\bigl(\int^0_x|f(t)|dt-\int^0_y|f(t)|dt\bigr)\to M\bigl(\int^0_{-\infty}|f(t)|dt-\int^0_y|f(t)|dt\bigr)$ as $x\to -\infty$.

Comment: Again, we let $y\to -\infty$, we get $M\bigl(\int^0_{-\infty}|f(t)|dt-\int^0_y|f(t)|dt\bigr)\to M\bigl(\int^0_{-\infty}|f(t)|dt-\int^0_{-\infty}|f(t)|dt\bigr)=0$ as $y\to -\infty$.
We conclude that $\int_x^yf^2(t)dt\to 0$ as $y>x$ and both $x,y\to -\infty$.

Now, let $\{x_n=n\}$, we have $\{\int^{0}_{x_n}f^2(t)dt\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$, which is complete, so $\{\int^{0}_{x_n}f^2(t)dt\}$ converges as $x_n\to -\infty$.
Am I right? thanks for your comment.

Comment: @StevenLu Yes, you are right.